# New apk from build.phonegap.com not working since 24th Sept

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I was building a small mobile application using phonegap build to build my apk.
It was working fine until 24th sept, 2015

But since 24th sept., the apk is not working properly.

Specially the pages which is fetching data from my server are not at all loading.

The app is working fine in browser until before I build the apk.

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<preference name='phonegap-version' value='cli-5.1.1' />
<preference name="android-build-tool" value="ant" />
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "com.phonegap.helloworld"
        version   = "1.0.0">
    <name>My app</name>
    <description>
        My app
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*"/>
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>

</widget>
```

Need some guidance over what has happen to the build.phonegap.com

Answer (score 0):

Change the plugin format like this, all the plugins as moved from pgb to npm

< gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />

Comment: I am not using any plugin because my app does not required it. Do I have to include plugin  then also?

Answer (score 0):

@Moumita,
recently, *Phonegap Build* did an upgrade for Apps that do NOT declare the compiler verison in their `config.xml` This happened on, or around the date you mentioned. Here is the [forum post](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/default-phonegap-version-is-now-cli-5-2-0)

Below is what you need to know. However, you may be able to just insert. The following line in your `config.xml` and it should return to normal.

`<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0" />`

**OTHERWISE Read what is below**
From the *Phonegap Build* Forum, [Petra Adds](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/no-support-for-ios9-yet#reply_16160589):

> I would add: without announcement, PGB changed the default PGB-version from 3.7.0 to cli-5.2.0. This causes all those who have not set 'phonegap-version' in config.xml to be confronted with the sudden need of splashscreen and whitelist plugins and additional whitelisting specifications in config and html.
>
> Also, several plugins seem not to build correctly with cli-5.2.0, causing log file error messages about "Class ***.java".

FWIW: *Phonegap Build* [admitted to as much in this tweet](https://twitter.com/jessemonroy650/status/648313365505310720)

From [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md) you have hit:

- #6 **Not setting the "phonegap version" for your compiler**
- #7 **Not setting "version" for you plugins**
- #10 **Not adding the new "white-list" and "white-list plugin" parameters in config.xml.**

For #6 & #7

> With the CLI version, if you do not assign a version for your platform OR in ''Phonegap Build'' if you do not set the phonegap-version in config.xml, YOU WILL GET THE LATEST VERSION. If you are lucky, your program just works as expected. If you are not lucky, you'll get a set of cascading error.
>
> Luckily for all of us, Holly Schinsky has written a nice blog post to explain it all:
>
> *Cordova/PhoneGap Version Confusion*
> http://devgirl.org/2014/11/07/cordovaphonegap-version-confusion/

For #10

> This relatively * NEW * requirement means – to access ANY website or resources on the web, you MUST use the whitelist and the whitelist plugin. This requirement goes into affect, if you are using cordova-android@4.0.0 or better; including cli-5.1.1. If however, your version is before 4.0.0, let use say 3.5.0 or 3.7.0, then you will *not* have to add the *white-list* requirement.
>
> To be clear, the "whitelist" has been around for a bit, but the plugin and requirement is very new. As you would expect, when the "whitelist" was added, the defacto open-access feature was deprecated. Or said another way, the defacto open-access feature was planned and scheduled to be eliminated. This change marks a step in removal of the open-access feature.
>
> In addition, the Content Security Policy (CSP) has caught numerous developers - because it was soooo poorly publicized. This CSP needs to go in every single HTML page you used, just like you have to wait for 'deviceready'. The documentation is buried in the bottom of many of the latest documentation pages.

**Related Links**

> Phonegap Build Forum: [Notes for upgrading to cli-5.1.1 on PGB](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/notes-for-upgrading-to-cli-5-1-1-on-pgb) and now required Whitelist
>
> - [Cordova Whitelist Guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html)
> - [Phonegap Whitelist Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide)
> - [Phonegap Build Whitelist Guide](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_access_elements.md.html#Access%20Elements)